# How would you split by \r\n if String.Split(String[]) did not exist?

Tags: c#, string, split, .net-micro-framework

Using the .NET MicroFramework which is a really cut-down version of C#.  For instance, [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc506617.aspx) barely has any of the goodies that we've enjoyed over the years.

I need to split a text document into lines, which means splitting by \r\n. However, String.Split only provides a split by char, not by string.

How can I split a document into lines in an efficient manner (e.g. not looping madly across each char in the doc)?

P.S. System.String is also missing a Replace method, so that won't work.
P.P.S. Regex is not part of the MicroFramework either.

Comment: It's not a cut-down version of C#; it's a cut-down version of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
string[] lines = doc.Split('\n');
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i+= 1)
   lines[i] = lines[i].Trim();
```

Assuming that the µF supports Trim() at all. Trim() will remove all whitespace, that might be useful. Otherwise use `TrimEnd('\r')`

Comment: Yep, this does the trick and keeps most of the performance characteristics.  Thanks. Pretty clever.

Comment: I was just about to suggest something like this - beat me to the punch. You may need to recombine strings (theoretically) if '\n' is not always preceded by '\r' in the input.

Answer (score 6):

I would loop across each char in the document, because that's clearly required. How do you think `String.Split` works? I would try to do so only hitting each character once, however.

Keep a list of strings found so far. Use `IndexOf` repeatedly, passing in the current offset into the string (i.e. the previous match + 2).

Comment: True, but the full .NET implementation of Split(string[]) uses pointers and unsafe code to achieve the performance that it does.  Otherwise, I would simply copy the code. 

I am operating on a really low end chip and was hoping for something exceedingly clever.

Comment: If you're only splitting by a single delimiter string, and the delimiter is longer than 3 character, you can get better performance using one of the Boyer-Moore search algorithm variants. Not that it helps the poster's problem, in this case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 3):

> How can I split a document into lines in an efficient manner (e.g. not looping madly across each char in the doc)?

How do you think the built-in `Split` works?

Just reimplement it yourself as an extension method.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
string path = "yourfile.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Or

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
string[] lines = content.Split(
    Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Readind that [.NET Micro Framework 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee437911.aspx), this code can work:

```
string line = String.Empty;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It splits by both items in the CharArray separately.  Thus, you'd get a bunch of empty results in addition to legit results.

Comment: @AngryHacker: RemoveEmptyEntries should deal with them;

Comment: File.ReadAllLines is not supported either.

Comment: See the link the provided in the question for documentation on what's supported.

Answer (score 0):

This may help in some scenario:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);    
string _Line = reader.ReadToEnd();
string IntMediateLine = string.Empty;
IntMediateLine = _Line.Replace("entersign", "");
string[] ArrayLineSpliter = IntMediateLine.Split('any specail chaarater');
```

Comment: In what scenarios? Can you provide some details please.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a *MicroFramework compatible* split function that works for an entire **string of characters**, here's one that does the trick, similar to the regular frameworks' version using StringSplitOptions.None:

```
    private static string[] Split(string s, string delim)
    {
        if (s == null) throw new NullReferenceException();

        // Declarations
        var strings = new ArrayList();
        var start = 0;

        // Tokenize
        if (delim != null && delim != "")
        {
            int i;
            while ((i = s.IndexOf(delim, start)) != -1)
            {
                strings.Add(s.Substring(start, i - start));
                start = i + delim.Length;
            }
        }

        // Append left over
        strings.Add(s.Substring(start));

        return (string[]) strings.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

Comment: I thought about turning this into an Extension Method as per [this possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344668/extension-methods-with-net-micro-framework)

Answer (score -1):

You can split your string with a substring.

```
String.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String theText = "word1 \n word2 \n word3";

string[] lines = theText.Split( new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or

```
string[] lines = theText.Split( new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

https://spacetech.dk/how-to-split-on-newline-in-c.html

https://www.bytehide.com/blog/split-string-csharp