# Extension methods with .NET Micro Framework

Tags: c#, extension-methods, .net-micro-framework

It seems that extensions methods are not supported/working with the .NET Micro Framework.

Is there any way to get this usefull language feature working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the [`ExtensionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx) class to your project you can use extension methods also in the .NET Micro Framework.

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

Comment: To be more precise, extension methods are a _compiler_ feature that merely relies on the existence of this attribute.